# app.post() method is not working in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mean-stack

I am new to MEAN Stack and have been developing some applications on Mean stack.But I am stuck with my app.post() method .The browser's console gives a 405 error saying that the method is not allowed.Please help me.

Here;s my code for server file in javascript

```
          var app              =express();
          var mongoose         =require('mongoose');
          var bodyParser       =require('body-parser');


      var urlencodedparser=app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
       var jsonParser = bodyParser.json()
       app.get('/',function(request,response){

        response.sendFile(__dirname+'/clients/views/index.html');
       });

       app.post('/api/meetups',jsonParser,function(req,res){


       console.log(req.body);
     });

    var port=process.env.PORT || 3000;
    app.listen(port,function(){

    console.log('Listening to the server at port '+port);   
     });
```

Comment: Please show how you're making requests to the post method. is it an API call, a form, etc?

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [Application.post()](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.post.method) Express documentation, I think you probably want to change the first line of your post listener from:

```
app.post('/api/meetups',jsonParser,function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

To this:

```
app.post('/api/meetups',function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

I don't think it takes the additional parameter you specified related to JSON parsing.  If you need to parse JSON you may want to look into using [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) with middleware like this (which you would put ABOVE the post listener):

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

Good luck!